# Dynamic popup menu that adds class to parent when radio button is selected (like Trello's)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, trello

## I want to create a dynamic popup menu that adds a class to "lists" parent when radio button is selected // removes classes when unselected (HTML structure below cannot change...only can change CSS and JS)

- I'm trying to make the "List Popup" popup directly under each "Green Gear" icon when clicked on/ hidden when clicked off (css classes).
- Whenever a radio button is selected from the popup, I need it to add a class directly into the corresponding list's parent div, while not effecting any of the other lists.
- The trick (for me) is making all of this happen dynamically with 1 popup menu that sits outside of each lists divs scope.
- The HTML structure cannot be changed (this has to be completely done w/ JS and CSS).

Here's what I've got so far: https://jsfiddle.net/oneeezy/t5eou67k/

```js
$(document).ready(function () {


/* Code to play with for show/hide popup

 


/* Code to play with for adding/removing classes when radio checked

 $('.list-layouts input').click(function () {
        $('.list-layouts input:not(:checked)').parent().removeClass("blue");
        $('.list-layouts input:checked').parent().addClass("blue");
    });    
*/    
    
});
```

```css
/* Reset Styles */
      * { box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
      h1 { padding: 0 0 .25rem; }
      h2 { line-height: 1.6; }
      aside { background: #e2e4e6; padding: 1rem; color: gray; margin: 1rem; border: 1px dashed gray; }
      aside ul { list-style: inside; }
      aside span { font-style: italic; color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .78); }
      .page { background: rgba(137, 96, 158, .17); margin: 2rem 0; padding: 2rem; position: relative; }
      .page::before { content: "<div> ...Scope"; color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .54); position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; }
      .page::after { content: "</div>"; color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .54); position: absolute; bottom: 0; left: 0; }
      .purple { background: rgba(137, 96, 158, .17); }
      .green { background: lime; }
      .yellow { background: yellow; }


      /* Trello (default tyles) */
      .wrapper { display: flex; }
      .list-wrapper { flex: 1; margin: 10px; }
      .list { background: #e2e4e6; position: relative; padding: 0 10px 3px; }
      .icon { display: block; position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0; width: 33px; height: 38px; background: lime; text-decoration: none; font-size: 2em; line-height: 1.3; color: darkgreen; }
      .card { display: block; height: 50px; background: white; border-radius: 3px; border: 1px solid #ccc; padding: .5em; margin: 0 0 .5em; }

      /* List Popup */
      .list-popup { display: block; width: 350px; max-height: 800px; background: yellow; border-radius: 3px; border: 1px solid #ccc; padding: 1em; }
      .list-popup p { padding: 0 0 1rem; }
      .list-popup p span::after { content: "<div class='list-wrapper'>"; }
      .list-layouts ul { list-style: none; }

      .list-normal {  }
      .list-normal .list {  }

      .list-color {  }
      .list-color .list *  { background: skyblue; }

      .list-bold {  }
      .list-bold .list * { font-weight: bold; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Description -->
    <aside>
    <h1>Dynamic popup menu that adds class to lists parent when radio button is selected // removes classes when unselected</h1>
    <ul>
      <li>I'm trying to make the <span class="yellow">"List Popup"</span> popup directly under each <span class="green">"Green Gear"</span> icon when clicked on/ hidden when clicked off (css classes).</li>
      <li>Whenever a radio button is selected from the popup, I need it to add a class directly into the corresponding list's parent div, while not effecting any of the other lists.</li>
      <li>The trick (for me) is making all of this happen dynamically with 1 popup menu that sits outside of each <span class="purple">lists divs scope</span>.</li>
    </ul>
    </aside>



    <!-- Lists -->
    <div class="page">
    <div class="wrapper">

      <div class="list-wrapper">
        <div class="list">
          <h2>List (1)</h2>
          <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon">⚙</a>

          <div class="card">Woohoo! Woohoo! Woohoo! </div>
          <div class="card">Woohoo! Woohoo! Woohoo! </div>
          <div class="card">Woohoo! Woohoo! Woohoo! </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="list-wrapper">
        <div class="list">
          <h2>List (2)</h2>
          <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon">⚙</a>

          <div class="card">Woohoo! Woohoo! Woohoo! </div>
          <div class="card">Woohoo! Woohoo! Woohoo! </div>
          <div class="card">Woohoo! Woohoo! Woohoo! </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="list-wrapper">
        <div class="list">
          <h2>List (3)</h2>
          <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon">⚙</a>

          <div class="card">Woohoo! Woohoo! Woohoo! </div>
          <div class="card">Woohoo! Woohoo! Woohoo! </div>
          <div class="card">Woohoo! Woohoo! Woohoo! </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    </div>

    <!-- List Layout popup -->
    <div class="page">
    <div id="listPopup" class="list-popup">
      <div>
        <h3>List Popup</h3>
        <p>These radio buttons should add a special class to the individual <span></span> when clicked on and removed when clicked off!</p>
      </div>

      <form class="list-layouts">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <input type="radio" name="listLayout" id="listNormal">
            <label for="listNormal">Normal</label>
          </li>
          <li>
            <input type="radio" name="listLayout" id="listColor">
            <label for="listColor">Bold</label>
          </li>
          <li>
            <input type="radio" name="listLayout" id="listBold">
            <label for="listBold">Italic</label>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </form>

    </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So first we will add the class to the list wrapper of the lists parent with the following code:

```
$('.icon').on('click', function () {
  if(!$('#listPopup').hasClass("open")){
      $('#listPopup').toggleClass("open");
  }
  $(this).parents('.list-wrapper').siblings().removeClass('blue');
  if(!$(this).parents('.list-wrapper').hasClass("blue")){
      $(this).parents('.list-wrapper').toggleClass("blue");
  }
});
```

Then we need to create an onchange function for the radios to find this class and add the new class to that list.

```
$('.list-layouts input').on('change', function () {
  var newClass = $(this).attr("id");
  // Remove the following statement if you want your classes to stack up
  $('.blue').removeClass("listNormal listColor listBold");
  $('.blue').addClass(newClass);
});
```

Here is a working fiddle of the whole thing in action [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wamosjk/fmx7gspr/)

Comment: Thanks for your help! You've made it very simple with the data-attributes, but I've got a few problems w/ this approach in its current form. The HTML structure I provided cannot change (I don't have access to it - I actually plan to use this code as a personal Chrome extension for Trello to recreate list layout w/ css). The '.list' div's also don't have #ID's, so I can't hook into them that way. My plan was to go 1 parent above '.list' to the '.list-wrapper', and add a custom class to the div...class='list-wrapper special-class'... - I'll be fiddlin' around w/ the code you've provided lol..

Comment: OK got ya so this actually makes the code much more simple.  I have edited my answer and changed the link to a new fiddle.  This is a much better way to go about it anyway.  Now it will toggle the class to the .list-wrapper and the onchange function will find the class and add a new class to that.

Comment: Great job man! Feel free to say no on this, but I've got a few more things to make happen for it to be 'perfect' for what I'm trying to accomplish. I've forked over your jsFiddle and listed my "Things to do" in the JS /* comments */ section (https://jsfiddle.net/oneeezy/busk89yx/)

Either way, I've accepted your answer since it's brought me much closer to my goal.

Comment: Are you trying to position the popup under the list or over the top of it or what exactly are you trying to do with it?  It may be easier to just have the popup overlay the page that would significantly cut down on the code that you need to use and may be more user friendly like this I just whipped up real quick https://jsfiddle.net/wamosjk/Lws3tx9h/.  But if not I will look at it and see what I can do.  I am kind of busy today but will probly get back with you tomorrow or something.  Let me know what exactly you are trying to accomplish with this and I will try to help out.

Comment: Also I know you said you don't have access to the html are you pulling this from a website or are you putting it in an iframe or how are you accessing the content?  Will it be on a page to where you can dynamically insert html into it?  I ask because it may be easier to dynamically create the popup and append it to the list.  Let me know about this comment and the previous one that I posted and I will try to help you work toward the best solution.  You can just add this to the javascript comments in your fiddle because it may be a lot to add in the comment section here and then let me know.

Comment: Just got home and had a little time so I signed up for trello to see what you are looking for.  I think I understand what you want.  Check out this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/wamosjk/3yyabw6t/ this will dynamically insert your popup into the list and should do everything that you want it to.  Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Hey there! Sorry I'm just getting this to you, I made a quick video to show you what I mean, https://youtu.be/D3Rn0EjPSj4

Comment: I'm checking it out on my mobile phone and that's pretty spot on! Much appreciation :D